# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined - AngularJS and jsPlumb connect

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, jsplumb

So I am trying to connect two elements that are created using angularjs by the user, with a curved line and I am getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined - AngularJS and jsPlumb connect

**A function in my service**

```
//this function adds a new object to the array of objects in sourceObject
function addNewDiv(sourceObject) {
    console.log('added a new subquestion');
    sourceObject.children.push({id: 'q-'+counter, anchor: 'a-'+counter});
    counter++;
    //return the newly created object so we can link the parent and child.
    var newObject = sourceObject.children[sourceObject.children.length-1];
    jsPlumb.connect({source: sourceObject.anchor, target: newObject.anchor});
}
```

so basically I am connecting my sourceObject with its newly created child and this is happening in one of my services. I am thinking that there is something going on with the dynamic creation of the elements but I am not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

As per jsPlumb documentation [Where does jsPlumb add elements?](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/home#container), jsPlumb expects the node elements to be part of the index.html DOM of anuglar JS.

since, in Angular JS, the view is generated by a main.html, jsPlumb is not able to find the source and target nodes in the DOM of container index.html having below div:

```
<div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
```